# How to make a file executable using Makefile

Tags: perl, makefile

I want to copy a particular file using Makefile and then make this file executable. How can this be done?
The file I want to copy is a .pl file.
For copying I am using the general cp -rp command. This is done successfully. But now I want to make this file executable using Makefile

Comment: Are you talking about `make install` or do you want to copy the file around in your source tree and use it to build further things?

Comment: I want to copy the file around in my source tree and use it to build further things. And make this file executable(can I use chmod to do this) If yes how?

Comment: you can directly use chmod command in makefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a bad practice to use `cp` and `chmod`, instead use `install` command.

```
all:
    install -m 0777 hello ../hello
```

You can use `-m` option with install to set the permission mode, and even note that by using the `install` you will preserve not only the permission but also the owner of the file.

You can still use chmod accordingly but it would be a bad practice

```
all:
    cp hello ../hello
    chmod +x ../hello
```

Update: `install vs cp`

1. cp would simply copy files with current permissions, install not only copies, but also can change perms/ownership as arg flags. (This is what your requirement was)
2. One significant difference is that cp truncates the destination file and starts copying data from the source into the destination file. install, on the other hand, removes the destination file first.
   This is significant because if the destination file is already in use, bad things could happen to whomever is using that file in case you cp a new file on top of it. e.g. overwriting an executable that is running might fail. Truncating a data file that an existing process is busy reading/writing to could cause pretty weird behavior. If you just remove the destination file first, as install does, things continue much like normal - the removed file isn't actually removed until all processes close that file.[[source]](https://superuser.com/questions/229883/how-is-install-c-different-from-cp)

For more details check these,

[install vs. cp; and mmap](http://en.chys.info/2009/05/install-vs-cp-and-mmap/)

[How is install -c different from cp](https://superuser.com/questions/229883/how-is-install-c-different-from-cp)

Comment: What is the advantage of using `install`?  I know it's customary practice, but why?